# FlutterFire/Firebase CLI: Failed to create iOS app for project myapp-e8cd7

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cli

I have been trying to register my flutter application with firebase in android studio, but it shows me this error:

```
abubakarshafiu@Abubakars-MBP myapp %  flutterfire configure -icom.ios.bubdle                                                                           
i Found 5 Firebase projects.                                                                                                                            
✔ Select a Firebase project to configure your Flutter application with · myapp-e8cd7 (MyApp)                                                            
✔ Which platforms should your configuration support (use arrow keys & space to select)? · android, ios, macos, web                                      
i Firebase android app com.example.myapp registered.                                                                                                    
i Firebase ios app com.ios.bubdle registered.                                                                                                           
✔ Which macos bundle id do you want to use for this configuration, e.g. 'com.example.app'? · 'com.example.myapp'?                                       
i Firebase macos app 'com.example.myapp'? is not registered on Firebase project myapp-e8cd7.                                                            
i Registered a new Firebase macos app on Firebase project myapp-e8cd7.                                                                                  
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create ios myapp (macos) --bundle-id='com.example.myapp'? --json --project=myapp-e8cd7 
ERROR: Failed to create iOS app for project myapp-e8cd7. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

i try applying this code but it still gave me the-same error

```
flutterfire configure -icom.ios.bubdle
```

How do i fix Failed to create iOS app for project myapp-e8cd7

Comment: Please edit the question and give us more information about what you want to achieve.

Comment: i mean i have been trying to register my flutter application with firebase in android studio but it shows me the above error that i pasted earlier on

Comment: "See firebase-debug.log for more info." Did you check that file? What does it say?

Comment: how can i check the file?

Comment: first of all this is what it shows to me. Which macos bundle id do you want to use for this configuration, e.g. 'com.example.app'? ·

Comment: then i have to write the my self

Answer (score 0):

i have found the answer that i have been questioning and no one give me the answer but letter on i realise that the problem is from my idle platform which is Android Studio which i have to tick the four column which are android, ios, mac and web columns. And also you should just go to your firebase console site  just copy and paste the root of your flutter project in which ever idle you are using.
[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjxEg.jpg)

[firebase console site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmKvs.png)